# How to send POST request from Android app to Rails application?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, spring, rest, spring-android

I have problem with sending POST request to my rails application from Android app (using Spring for Android)

I have following Rails controller:

```
  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json

  def create
@user = User.new(user_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
  end
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
end
```

I'm sending POST request (using Spring for Android):

```
        RestTemplate restTemplatePost = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplatePost.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());


        UserDto user = new UserDto();
        user.name = "testName";
        user.email = "test@fromandroid.com";

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String request = gson.toJson(user);
        restTemplatePost.postForObject(createUserUrl, request, String.class);
        } catch(RestClientException e) {
            Log.e("POST",e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
```

value of String request is {"email":"test@fromandroid.com","name":"testName"}

and createUserUrl has value of: `http://10.0.0.2:3000/users`

however, I still get the following error:

```
> W/RestTemplate(3299): POST request for "http://10.0.0.2:3000/users"
> resulted in 400 (Bad Request); invoking error handler
```

I'm able to send the GET request, but POST doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? 
I used CURL to get better error message and it returns:

```
param not found: user
```

so the problem might be with required user and optional name and emails parameters which are accepted by REST API, but how should I format user in json for it to work?

I'd greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure that your controller config accept POST method, may be it just receives GET.

[RailsController](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)

[RailsRouting](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)

And you can use RestClient (Plugin of Firefox or Chrome) to test your api.

[Rest Client - Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/)

[Rest Client - Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo)

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues you must have to follow to `post`.

1. you need to post data something like:

   `{"user_params" : {"email":"test@fromandroid.com","name":"testName"}}`

   to create a user (according to your controller).
2. To post data add **Request Header**. As you sending `json` data, so header will be `Content-Type: application/json`.

Also I'm suggesting you to use a FireFox addons is named "[RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/)" to simulate this scenario.

Thanks.

Comment: thanks for answer. Apparently, the number 1. is not quite correct. It should be either: {"user" : {"email":"test@fromandroid.com","name":"testName"}} or simply {"email":"test@fromandroid.com","name":"testName"}. Just checked and both work. I think the problem is with the way I'm using Spring for Android. Didn't quite solve it yet, but I'm almost sure I need to use different converters. Thanks for mentioning RestClient addon - really helpful!